# A question on irreducible characters.

Tags: group-theory, characters, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $Irr(G)$ be the set of irreducible characters of $G$ and let $Aut(G)$ be the automorphism group of $G$. It can be seen that 
$\chi^\beta \in Irr(G)$ if $\beta$ is an inner automorphism and $\chi^\beta(x)=\chi(\beta(x))$. In general is it true that $$\chi^\beta \in Irr(G) \text{ for all }\beta\in Aut(G)?$$

Comment: Note $Tr(AB) = Tr(BA)$ implies $\chi= \chi^\beta$ for inner automorphisms ($\chi$ is a class function). Then the automorphisms of $G$ permute its set of representations and preserve the subrepresentation relation, thus it permutes the irreducible ones. Complex representations with the same character are isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Irreducible characters cannot be written as sums of other characters.

Hint: $(\chi_1+\chi_2)^{\beta}=\chi_1^{\beta}+\chi_2^{\beta}$.

Answer (score 3):

@runway44's answer is already complete (and should be the one accepted), but just to have an alternative answer:

For a character $\chi\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$ it is known that $\chi$ is irreducible if and only if
$$(\chi,\chi)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\overline{\chi(g)}=1.$$
Use the definition of $\chi^\beta$ to compute $(\chi^\beta,\chi^\beta)$, under the assumption that $\chi$ is irreducible.